# Modeling an inbox in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing an app that allows users to feed their inbox, then process their input, making it either a note or a task.

Since I need notes and tasks to behave very differently, I plan on using different models for them.

The question is: how do I go about changing inbox items into notes or tasks?

My first idea was to write an action that would destroy an inbox item and call the create action on the notes (or tasks) controller, but that does not seem right.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Update**

I'm looking into polymorphic associations as a solution for this, as suggested by @Dipak.

This is my schema: (sorry I can't paste the code. I'm using a web based ssh tool)

**I have decided to use the Idea model to define inbox items**

[image]

And these are my models:

[image]

I want to be able to click this link (on my partial)

[image]

and have it do two things:

1. create a task
2. assign this task to idea.thought

How should I do this? Is this the proper way to use this kind of association?

Answer (score 0):

As per your question it seems like your few initial fields are same for all notes and tasks, that you calling inbox. So better you can save those fields in different table and other fields in related table.

For such situation you should use polymorphic association. You can read about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). So your new inbox table should be intermediate table used for polymorphic association.

Comment: I'm still lost. Can you elaborate? Should I use something like `belongs_to :inbox_item, polymorphic: true` on my Note and Task models, and then, on my inbox page, filter records based on their belonging (or not) to a note/task?

Comment: Yes this is what i asking. Consider imageable as your inbox model in rails guide and go ahead.

Comment: But how should I go about turning an inbox item into a task, for example? I need a link next to the item, something like "Make this a task", but what action should it call? In this case, I'd have to update said item's task_id attribute, but first I'd have to create a task with that id, which implies two controllers. (Back to my original question)